# Magento 2 Table missing catalogrule_product_replica

Tags: database, magento2.2, upgrade

My magento version is 2.2.2
I tried to upgrade my version into 2.2.5CE
But it shows an error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table
>   'amsi_shopmgnto.catalogrule_product_replica' doesn't exist in engine,
>   query was: SELECT COUNT(1) AS `rows` FROM
>   `catalogrule_product_replica`

I checked it in my db the table entry is there but when I tried to retrieve the columns it showed an error

> Error Code: 1932. Table 'catalogrule_product_replica'
>   doesn't exist in engine

Any solution for this issue? My cron is not working I can't update my version also.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Camit1dk I hav't got any solution for this, what i did is a simple hack, I re-created that table, by coping sql from my local server. It is working till now. I don't know what will be the end result. Still looking for a good solution.

Comment: @Camit1dk Could you give us the command to recreate the table please

Comment: @MerGh sorry i did not find solution  and not able to recreated. Can you try to reindex its may be regenerate this table.

Answer (score 0):

Try create/recreate table with this sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalogrule_product_replica`;
CREATE TABLE `catalogrule_product_replica` (
  `rule_product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rule Product Id',
  `rule_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Rule Id',
  `from_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'From Time',
  `to_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'To time',
  `customer_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `action_operator` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'to_fixed' COMMENT 'Action Operator',
  `action_amount` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Action Amount',
  `action_stop` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Action Stop',
  `sort_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Sort Order',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website Id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`rule_product_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_EAA51B56FF092A0DCB795D1CEF812B7B` (`rule_id`,`from_time`,`to_time`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`product_id`,`sort_order`),
  KEY `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID` (`customer_group_id`),
  KEY `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  KEY `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_FROM_TIME` (`from_time`),
  KEY `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_TO_TIME` (`to_time`),
  KEY `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='CatalogRule Product';
```